# How to fire javascript event in code behind?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose I have js for asp textbox onchnage event. I hook it up in code behind in Page_Load event like:

```
MyTextBox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "testjs();")
```

Then I change MyTextBox.Text in code behind for a asp DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged event(set AutoPostBack="true") like

```
MyTextBox.Text = 123
```

but onchange event for MyTextBox not fired.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Register a manual call to `testjs();` after changing `MyTextBox`

```
Page.ClientScript
    .RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "testjs", "testjs();", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClientScriptManager to kick-off a JS function from code-behind (I am assuming you use VB.NET):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "JSCode", "testjs();", True)
```

Note: If you use any controls that employ MS Ajax (e.g. UpdatePanel) as containers for your textbox - you have to use ScriptManager instead:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "JSCode", "testjs();", True)
```